# i have a question a android programming for media play code

Tags: android

When the media is already playing in the background and you want to play the media in another app, I want to stop the media that was playing and stop the media that was playing after receiving the signal from the existing app. In other words, I want to detect the signal to stop the existing media playback signal if there is another media playback signal.

I think it might be related to android AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED by calling android requestAudioFocus (), please help.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, @Eric Brown if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 2):

from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#automatic-ducking)

read the documentation. it explains everything.

in `OnAudioFocusChangeListener` you can listen when another app has audio focus and you can respond to the changes.

for example:

```
AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener =
  new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
      if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
        // Permanent loss of audio focus
        // Pause playback immediately
        mediaController.getTransportControls().pause();
        // Wait 30 seconds before stopping playback
        handler.postDelayed(delayedStopRunnable,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30));
      }
      else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT) {
        // Pause playback
      } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK) {
        // Lower the volume, keep playing
      } else if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
        // Your app has been granted audio focus again
        // Raise volume to normal, restart playback if necessary
      }
    }
  };
```

let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: But I’m trying to hurry affection in program for your flight answer

Comment: sure, if you have more questions post them. we are all here to help. good luck.

Comment: HI @EricBrown , if answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.